# Python3 .replace yielding TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to read the output from a server with this code:

```
s = paramiko.SSHClient()
s.load_system_host_keys()
s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
s.connect(hostname, port, username, password)
command = 'xe vm-list'
(stdin, stdout, stderr) = s.exec_command(command)

output = stdout.read()
x = output.replace("\n", ",").strip()
print(x)
s.close()
```

When the line "x = output.replace("\n", ",").strip()" is run "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" is thrown.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `output` seems to be a string of bytes; you'll want to decode that to (character) string before applying `replace` - something like `output.decode('utf-8').replace("\n", ",").strip()`, adjusted to the specific encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decode bytes object to get string.  To do this:

```
output = stdout.read().decode("UTF-8")
```

in there replace UTF-8 with the encoding of your remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

`output` is a `bytes` object, not `str`. You need to pass its `replace` method `bytes` as well, in this case by adding a `b` prefix to the literals:

```
x = output.replace(b"\n", b",").strip()
```